# Dimension of a unit normal vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Question: What exactly is the dimension of a unit normal vector?

This is something I haven't before gave any thoughts to. But in a physics text-whilst trying to understand a derivation-the assumption I made was that the dimension has to be $\left [ \hat{n} \right ]=m$.

I haven't been able to find any satisfying answer to this anywhere.

A clarification would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by dimension. Typically, dimension is defined for vector spaces rather than vectors and vectors can be considered to be dimensionless (see this: [Is a vector and a unit vector dimensionless?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172829/is-a-vector-and-a-unit-vector-dimensionless)).

If by dimension you mean number $n$ in an $n$-tuple $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$, then the unit normal vector of an $(n-1)$-dimensional hypersurface in $n$-dimensional space has dimension $n$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)#Hypersurfaces_in_n-dimensional_space)).